# GetString of Composite Type Postgres?

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jdbc

I created this table:

```
CREATE TABLE public.luogo
(
id_luogo integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('luogo_id_luogo_seq'::regclass),
tipo character varying(30) NOT NULL,
indirizzo indirizzo,
CONSTRAINT luogo_pk PRIMARY KEY (id_luogo)
)
```

where indirizzo type is

```
CREATE TYPE public.indirizzo AS
(
citta character varying(50),
via character varying(50),
cap integer,
civico integer
);
```

So I'm using JDBC and I need this query

```
"SELECT * FROM luogo WHERE id_luogo= '"+variable+"'";
```

The problem is that `resultset.getstring("indirizzo")` returns obviously a string like: "(value,value,value)". How to get as string the singular parameters of indirizzo?

Comment: String concatenation in a query string is vulnerable to SQL injection, you should use a prepared statement with parameters instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct SQL syntax is:

```
"SELECT id_luogo,(indirizzo).citta FROM luogo"
```

To get the String in Java is: resultset.getString("citta")